# Run PHP function inside Bash (and keep the return in a bash variable)

Tags: bash, php

I am trying to run a PHP function inside Bash... but it is not working.

```
#! /bin/bash

/usr/bin/php << 'EOF'
<?php echo getcwd(); ?>
EOF
```

In the reality, I needed to keep the return value in a bash variable... By the way, I am using the php's getcwd() function only to illustrate the bash operation.

**UPDATE:** Is there a way to pass a variable?

```
VAR='/$#'
php_cwd=`/usr/bin/php << 'EOF'
<?php echo preg_quote($VAR); ?>
EOF`
echo "$php_cwd"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please do not edit answers to add your question in it. Instead edit edit your own question and comment on the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
php_cwd=`/usr/bin/php << 'EOF'
<?php echo getcwd(); ?>
EOF`
echo "$php_cwd" # Or do something else with it
```

Answer (score 8):

```
PHP_OUT=`php -r 'echo phpinfo();'`
echo $PHP_OUT;
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively:

```
php_cwd = `php -r 'echo getcwd();'`
```

replace the getcwd(); call with your php code as necessary.

EDIT: ninja'd by David Chan.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can inline PHP commands within the shell i.e. *sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

export VAR="variable_value"
php_out=$(php << 'EOF'
<?
    echo getenv("VAR"); //input
?>
EOF)
>&2 echo "php_out: $php_out"; #output
```

Answer (score 1):

Use '-R' of php command line. It has a build-in variable that reads inputs.

```
VAR='/$#'
php_cwd=$(echo $VAR | php -R 'echo preg_quote($argn);')
echo $php_cwd
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me:

```
VAR='/$#'
php_cwd=`/usr/bin/php << EOF
<?php echo preg_quote("$VAR"); ?>
EOF`
echo "$php_cwd"
```

Answer (score -2):

I have a question - why don't you use functions to print current working directory in bash?
Like:

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd # prints current working directory.
```

Or

```
#!/bin/bash
variable=`pwd`
echo $variable
```

**Edited**: Code above changed to be working without problems.

Comment: That really doesn't answer OP's question. The code also does not produce OP's expected output. Lastly, questions should be comments, not answers.

Comment: Well, it was rhetorical question to be honest. Well, I have mistyped the second part of the code and going to edit it now to the point it will work. For the first part of your comment - yes, it does not answer the question absolutely strictly the same way it poster wants to, but - if he/she wants to save it as a bash variable, why use php??

Comment: I used the php's getcwd() function only to illustrate the bash operation. It's just a cummon example to make the question simpler.

Comment: Oh, for that I'm sorry @netcoder, @Roger. It seemed to me little strange to use php in bash, so I thought you were looking for a way to get the path.

Comment: I am the one who has to apologize.