# How to pass bash script variable value in PHP command (CLI)

Tags: php, linux, bash

I need help in passing the Linux bash-script variable to execute the PHP CLI command.

I am working on the bash-script that executes PHP CLI command that gets input variable from the bash-script like folder-path to include a file for accessing a class of the PHP file.

But what happens while executing the bash-script is that the variable passed to the PHP CLI-command act as a variable for PHP.

Below is the sample-code my script

```
file="$folderpath"somefile.php
mage_version=$(php -r 'include "$file";print_r(Mage::getVersionInfo());')
```

Below is the error I am getting

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: file in Command line code on line 1
PHP Warning:  include(): Filename cannot be empty in Command line code on line 1
```

Comment: Try using curly brackets `${folderpath}` and `${file}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash needs double (`"`) quotes to parse variable, otherwise they will stay `$var` and so php will read them;

```
file="$folderpath"somefile.php
mage_version=$(php -r "include \"${file}\";print_r(Mage::getVersionInfo());")
```

[More inline bash info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash)

If you need a multi line solution, you can do something like: [Run PHP function inside Bash (and keep the return in a bash variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231991/run-php-function-inside-bash-and-keep-the-return-in-a-bash-variable)

```
php_cwd=`/usr/bin/php << 'EOF'
<?php echo getcwd(); ?>
EOF`
echo "$php_cwd" # Or do something else with it
```

Comment: `php -r 'require '\"${loc}\"'; echo implode(".",$OC_Version);'`  I had to use single quotes so that `$OC_Version` was not pre evaluated but taken literally as that is a variable for php not bash